# Streaming Team Fortress 2

Tags: team-fortress-2, streaming

I need some help in streaming Team Fortress 2. I installed Open Broadcaster and selected 'Game Capture' and the TF2 process, but when I preview the stream all I get is a black screen. The Game Capture works for Minecraft and other games but not for TF2.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Re-check the process you selected, it's possible that TF2 uses a different one to render graphics.

Comment: It's the only TF2 process that shows up in the drop down menu.

Comment: Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make sure that both the game and the streaming software are running off of the same graphics card. It looks like your computer has two graphics cards. An integrated and a discrete.

Answer (score 4):

I found out what was going on. I play on a laptop that has two different graphics cards. An integrated card and a discrete graphics card. When you use Open Broadcaster make sure the game AND OBS are running off of the same graphics card. In my case, I had to go into the Nvidia control panel and manually set OBS to run on the discrete graphics card.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Nvidia, go to the Nvidia control panel, and select customize applications. There you should be able to change which video adapter OBS runs on. Restart the application and that should solve your black screen problem